# Updating existing document in Firebase using Flutter causes Lost Of Connection to the Simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an existing map in Firebase that I'm trying to update with Flutter.  Executing the code 'await documentReference.update()' causes the simulator to lose connection.

Network connectivity is good.
Rules are good.[image: The map/list that I'm trying to update the existing map/list with.]

'''await documentReference.update(outerMap);'''

[image: Existing Firebase Collection]